# Azure DevOps boards styles - Parent field empty

Tags: azure-devops

We аre trying to implement items on a board in Azure DevOps which are colored in case they have no "Parent" associated with them. Currently, we are struggling with the correct value clause here.

We have tried different things like "does not contain" "*" or "[Any]" however this is not working. What would be the correct Operator and Value we need to use here?

[image: Azure DevOps Board Styles]

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation ([Customize cards on a Kanban board](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/customize-cards?view=azure-devops)), you can use `Parent` only to show `Parent Title`:

> To show the Title of the parent work item, choose the Parent field.
> Choosing the Parent title from a card opens the parent work item. To
> change the parent work item, open the child work item and remove the
> link and add a different parent work item. You can filter your board
> based on parent work items, whether the Parent field is added to cards
> or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is a report on the developers community that explains that behavior: [Cannot set styling rule for parent field](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-set-styling-rule-for-parent-field/1169228?space=21&entry=problem)